# Desktop capture chrome plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was developing a chrome plugin in which captures desktop screen. I am using the sample plugin example given here...
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#desktop-capture-example
But in this example as we click the start button a dialog pop ups which asks the user which screen or window to share but I want to share my current screen what changes do I make in 
this code

```
// Copyright 2013 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

function gotStream(stream) {
  console.log("Received local stream");
  var video = document.querySelector("video");
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  localstream = stream;
  stream.onended = function() { console.log("Ended"); };
}

function getUserMediaError() {
  console.log("getUserMedia() failed.");
}

function onAccessApproved(id) {
if (!id) {
  console.log("Access rejected.");
   return;
}
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
audio:false,
video: { mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
                        chromeMediaSourceId: id } }
  }, gotStream, getUserMediaError);
 }

 var pending_request_id = null;

 document.querySelector('#start').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 pending_request_id = chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
 ["screen"], onAccessApproved); 
 });

document.querySelector('#cancel').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 if (pending_request_id != null) {
 chrome.desktopCapture.cancelChooseDesktopMedia(pending_request_id);
}
});
```

what should be the value of the chromeMediaSourceId so that the default selection is the current screen;

basically i want to avoid this screen ..
[image]

Plz help...
Regards

Comment: From looking at the docs, it's impossible. The user has to confirm the stream source, even if there's only one option to choose.

Comment: I set the chromeMediaSource as "screen" Now everytime it's choosing screen as capture. But dialog is still coming I need to find a way to remove that dialog..

Comment: It's impossible. Consider that a security feature "user must consent to screen sharing". More questions?

Comment: Security is no issue because now an additional dialog is coming...which says. Do you want to share your screen ?

Comment: Hey I got it.... just remove the chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia() and add direct callback..and remove the if(id) condition and set chromeMediaSource: screen

Comment: It's great if you could get it to work; I apologize for my insistence that it's impossible. Make sure you add your solution as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. The manifest permission allows you to provide this feature but the user still has to select the screen and hit share.

Like others said, this is a security feature to prevent your extension from triggering this without informing the user.

Comment: @Deepak : Can you please share in details what have you done to set share screen as default? Did not understand direct callback? Thanks!