# Chrome extension hide screensharing message window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, getusermedia

[image]

After user allow my extension to share his screen this message will appear.

Is there any way to prevent this or hide somehow?

Comment: Do you not see the "Hide" button in your screenshot?

Comment: When I click hide window is minimized to application bar. I need to hide this window or remove completely

Comment: It is a security precaution so users know their screen is being shared.

Comment: User selected what to share before through `desktopCapture` API. He knows that his screen is shared. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162346/desktop-capture-chrome-plugin

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this when using chrome desktop capture APIs. It is a security feature to ensure users know that their screen is being shared. You can hide it to the taskbar, but that's as hidden as it can be.

Answer (score -2):

Just Click the blue hide button And It Will Hide It

Comment: Did you notice [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30778219/chrome-extension-hide-screensharing-message-window/64835654#comment49613112_30778219) saying "When I click hide window is minimized to application bar. I need to hide this window or remove completely"?